# Is Apple Cinema Display 27" Thunderbolt good choice for software developer?

Tags: display, hardware-recommendation

I am a software developer currently working on a Macbook Pro Retina 15". The Retina display on my Macbook Pro works well for me.

I am considering a 27" Apple Thunderbolt Display.

Is the Apple display significantly more glossy then the retina Macbook Pro and if so, is it enough to pose a problem after long hours of use?

Comment: bought. I am quite happy with it. As much as you can be with glossy display. It's extra sharp and beautiful image. You can easily edit code, and test on ios simulator, or read tutorial. The wonderful staff is thunderbolt connection which overs you acces to built in: ethernet, thunderbolt, camera, microphone, charger(magsafe -< magsafe2 converter needed, 3x USB 2.0, FireWire). What is great extension for small macbooks and mac mini.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Apple Cinema Display and Thunderbolt display are excellent monitors for long term use.

Whether the glossy screen will cause you issues is more about the environment you use it in.  If your room has a great deal of light behind you the reflection might be an issue, but in a normal indoor environment they're fine.

IMHO, the ACD/TBD doesn't really offer a software developer anything unique to justify it's price premium over average monitors.  I'd buy it for the TB connections, brightness and color accuracy more than anything else, but for software develop those things usually don't matter.